# Spring Roo enhanced Grid pagination

Tags: spring, spring-roo, dojo, dojox.grid

I'm trying to add Pagination to enhanced Grid, I'm adding the following

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.IndirectSelection");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Pagination");
```

But I'm running into

```
Error: Could not load 'dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Pagination';
       last tried '../dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Pagination.js'
Source File: http://localhost:8080/adms/resources/dojo/dojo.js Line: 14
```

Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the pagination plugin is not part of the Spring JS resources.  I am using version 2.3.0 of that package, which is the latest available release at this point.